# How to search for value in a sequence in Python?

Tags: python, sequence

I am very new to coding so please bear with me.  Basically I am writing a program that will ask for either a last name or id number, then search a .csv file for the word and return the entire column to which it belongs.  Below is what I have written if the user opts to search by the id.

```
method = input("Search by invoice id (id) or customer last name (lname)?: ")
    data = "data.csv"
    dataFile = open(data, "r")
    dataRows = dataFile.readlines()

if method == "id":
    term = input("Enter the id: ")
    for line in dataRows:
        row = line.strip()
        newRow = row.split('\n')
        if term == newRow[0]:
            print(newRow)
        else:
            print("No matches found.")
```

This is the csv file:
[image: Here is a photo of the csv file.]

This is how it prints out after readlines():

```
['invoice id,first name,last name,part number,quantity,total']
['111,Jim,Morrison,27,1,50.25']
['222,Ray,Manzarek,25,2,64.46']
['333,John,Densmore,16,4,34.34']
['333,Robby,Krieger,32,2,34.34']
['555,Jim,Morrison,12,4,43.34']
['333,Jim,Morrison,35,2,34.76']
['888,John,Densmore,63,2,34.76']
['111,Robby,Krieger,21,1,64.45']
['458,Freddie,Mercury,32,4,45.23']
['111,Freddie,Mercury,21,1,46.2']
['234,Allie,McGuire,43,3,64.45']
['675,Allie,McGuire,32,4,45.23']
['359,Freddie,Mercury,423,2,34.34']
```

Since invoice ID is the first column, I thought it would be found by using if term ==newRow[0], but that's not working. Any tips? Thanks so much.

Comment: you should use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module when handling CSVs. all of the row splitting and other operations are taken care of for you

Comment: @RoadRunner i added it, thank you!

Comment: If the data is comma separated, shouldn't it be: `newRow = row.split(',')`?

Comment: @aydow unfortunately our teacher hasn't taught us that, but good idea!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp ooh that helped!                                                              Search by invoice id (id) or customer last name (lname)?: id
Enter your search term: 111
No matches found.
['111', 'Jim', 'Morrison', '27', '1', '50.25']
No matches found.
No matches found.
No matches found.
No matches found.
No matches found.
No matches found.
['111', 'Robby', 'Krieger', '21', '1', '64.45']
No matches found.
['111', 'Freddie', 'Mercury', '21', '1', '46.2']
No matches found.
No matches found.
No matches found. But now it keeps saying no matches found if the id doesn't match

Comment: All that extra stuff is because you print a fail message for every line that is not a match. You need to only print the fail message after you have searched the entire file and not found a match.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I tried adding if term != newRow[0]:
        print("no match found"), but that doesn't work either. I know I need to write this section outside of the loop but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Before the loop: create a flag `found=False`. If you find a match, set `found=True`. After the loop: `if !found: print("No matches found.")`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is using the `csv` module:

```
method = input('Search by invoice id (id) or customer last name (lname)?: ')
term = input('Enter the term: ')

found_row = None     # To store the row if a match is found

with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        # Compare term with Invoice ID if chosen method is ID
        # else compare with Last Name
        if term == (row['invoice id'] if method == 'id' else row['last name']):
            found_row = row

if found_row:
    print(row)
else:
    print('No match found')
```

If you're allowing the user to search by ID or last name only, it's possible to simplify your input even further by asking them to enter 1 for ID and 2 for Last Name. This approach is inflexible but the advantage is that users are less likely to enter the method in wrong case. For example, you're comparing `method == 'id'` but the user might enter `Id` or `ID`. Might make your life a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `csv` module for this problem, then you should `split` your string on `","`, not on `"\n"`:

```
newRow = row.split(",")
```

This way, the first element of `newRow` will be the invoice id.

Comment: That worked! Is there any way to count how many records came up? For example, when searching for ID number 111, there are three separate sequences that have that ID number.  I want to add "3 records found" but im not quite sure how

Comment: You could add a counter and iterate through all records using a for loop; you would add a statement like `counter = 0` before the start of your `for` loop and add the statement `counter += 1` right below your `if` statement.

Comment: I did :       if method == "id":
    term = input("Enter your search term: ")
    count = 0 
    for line in dataRows:
        row = line.strip()
        newRow = row.split(',')
        if term == newRow[0]:
            count =+ 1
            print(line)
            print("{0} records found".format(count))  but unfortunately this was the out come 111,Jim,Morrison,27,1,50.25

1 records found
111,Robby,Krieger,21,1,64.45

1 records found
111,Freddie,Mercury,21,1,46.2

1 records found